# Solving Matrix Equation $(A^T)^{-1}X+(\frac12B)^{-1}=(B^{-1}A^T)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$$(A^T)^{-1}X+(\tfrac12B)^{-1}=(B^{-1}A^T)^{-1}\implies X=B-2A^TB^{-1}$$
I've asked yesterday about one similar equation and I always get stuck, if someone could help me! :)

Comment: I think it's the basic that I'm missing, at one point I think I am only multiplying the second member.

Comment: Do you need how to solve the equation?

Comment: Yes, to the X. And the image is basically saying the first equation is equal to the second one.

Comment: Are all matrices square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A,B\in M_{nxn}$ two matrices with the same dimension, There some properties that I used
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (B^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}=(A^{T})^{-1}(B^{-1})^{-1}; \hspace{0.3cm} (\frac{1}{2}B)^{-1}=2B^{-1}; \hspace{0.3cm} A^{T}(A^{T})^{-1}=I
\end{eqnarray*}
So:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(A^{T})^{-1}X+(\frac{1}{2}B)^{-1}&=&(B^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}\\
(A^{T})^{-1}X&=&(B^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}-(\frac{1}{2}B)^{-1}\\
X&=&(A^{T})((B^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}-(\frac{1}{2}B)^{-1}))\\
X&=&A^{T}(B^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}-A^{T}(\frac{1}{2}B)^{-1}))\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Then $X=B-2A^{T}B^{-1}$

Comment: In the 3rd step when you pass the transpose to the other side does the -1 disappears?

Comment: Yes, in both sides, I multiply $A^{T}$

Comment: Oh okay thanks I didn't know about $(A^T A^T)^-1$

Comment: Sorry, I've edited this post

Answer (score 0):

$$(A^T)^{-1} X+(1/2B)^{-1} = (B^{-1} A^T)^{-1}
$$Hi welcome to MSE

as a hint
$$(A^T)^{-1} =(A^{-1})^T$$and
$$(B^{-1} A^T)^{-1}=(A^{T})^{-1}(B^{-1})^{-1}$$also $$(1/2B)^{-1}=2B^{-1}$$